# Setting values for a textfield by .value

Tags: javascript, html

I know that this should be a really easy question, but I have no idea why a value cannot be assigned to a text field? I've also tried the getElementById by assigning the input an id, but that too doesn't work. I've been struggling with this for the past 3hours. Am I doing something completely wrong?

Javascript is

```
  document.form1.hello.value= "123";
```

HTML is

```
    <form name="form1" class="" action="index.html" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="hello" value="">
    </form>
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hello' of undefined is the error.

full version is

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.form1.hello.value= "123";
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="form1" class="" action="index.html" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="hello" value="">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't get elements like that. Read 'bout selectors first: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp

Comment: @KidBinary Of course you can? `document.forms.form1.elements.hello` would be better, but the OPs code should work

Comment: Where is the JS code in the html? Please post your complete page

Comment: Where's the code that involved giving the `<input>` an id value?

Comment: Your code works fine

Comment: the easiest approach here would be to give an id to your input type="text" and then `document.getElementById('your-id').value = "123"`

Comment: http://jsbin.com/tecuxerilo/1/edit?html,js,output — I can't reproduce the problem. Whatever is causing it is not exposed by the question. Try providing a real [MCVE]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I feel like my basics are really weak.

Comment: Sounds like you're executing your script before the elements exist. For instance, if you've put the `script` in the `head` of the document rather than at the end of `body` where it belongs.

Comment: @Bergi: Right. Misunderstood the question first.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes you were right!! that just fixed the problem completely. Thank you so much. How can I learn more about these rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi peak your code is working fine

```
<form name="form1" class="" action="index.html" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="hello" value="">
</form>

document.form1.hello.value= "123"
```

please check this code pen for me it is working fine verify once
http://codepen.io/vkvicky-vasudev/pen/ZpBbkR

the code which you have written in that put 
script tag inside body

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>

</head>
<body>
<form name="form1" class="" action="index.html" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="hello" value="">
</form>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    document.form1.hello.value= "123";
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

here is code pen
http://codepen.io/vkvicky-vasudev/pen/YGpymP

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know the order was what was causing the issue.

Comment: exactly that was the issue

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> 
    
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    
      function onLoadFunction(){
      
        document.getElementById('text_input').value = '123';
      
      }
      
    </script>
      
  </head>
  <body onload="onLoadFunction()">
    
     <input type='text' id='text_input' value='' />
    
   </body>
</html>
```